# Is it possible to recover data after GPT to MBR conversion and repartitioning?

Tags: data-recovery, mbr, gpt

I tried to install Windows that requires MBR system to a GPT system. I converted GPT to MBR using `diskpart` utility. After it all my logical disks disappeared and only one (with total amount of space) was left. I divided it into two parts and installed Windows on one of them. Everything is OK but I need some data from my old disappeared logical disks.

Is there a way or is it possible to recover data somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to say that the chance of recovery from this is very small, your time will be better spent recreating the lost data and/or working out how you are going to get on without it.

If you want to try to recover the data, your best bet is to **immediately** power off the computer, take that disk out and take it to a data recovery specialist. The kind of low level stuff you would need to do to get at any traces of data that may remain is way beyond what we can go into on a forum like this (not that I understand it anyway).

I'm afraid to say this is a very expensive process and has a very small chance of success.

There will certainly not be any way to recover data by installing one of the recovery utilities or booting to a recovery live CD.

Comment: I have to agree with Patrick. I work in a computer store and the cost of these kinds of data recovery usually start at 500 euro. These disks spend days to weeks hooked onto a computer rebuilding the whole structure tree.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick is basically correct, but there are tools you can use to try to recover your data yourself. Depending on how you partitioned your disk, [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) may be able to recover some of your partitions, although they may have some damage. The [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) utility, or similar Windows-only tools, are more likely to be able to recover a subset of your files. In both cases, the fact that you've re-installed the OS means that the chances of your recovering *all* your files is minuscule, even if you hand the disk over to a specialized and pricey shop.

To maximize your chances of success, power off the computer immediately. (Don't even use the shutdown option; just pull the plug.) *Any* continued use of the computer runs the risk of overwriting more of the data you want to recover. Also, this type of operation is inherently risky, so you should have a complete low-level backup of your disk before you begin. This means you'll need a spare disk that's at least as large as the one you want to recover.

If your data are at all important, it's better to hand the disk over to an expert than to try to do it yourself. The low-level recovery tools I've just suggested can be tricky to use. You can easily make matters worse or simply fail to recover data if you're not an expert.